# Unity 3d Quaternion Rotation Lerp of 3d Object

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions, lerp

I am working on a Unity project. There is a car wiper and i want to rotate it in a way that when I pres "wipers toggle on" wipers start rotating from 0,0,0 to 0,0,-45 and start lerping. But when I press "wipers toggle off" the wipers must rotate back to 0,0,0. For example if current wipers rotation are 0,0,-20 and I press the "wipers toggle off"  key they wipers must be rotateTowards 0,0,0. Also, If I press "wipers toggle on" again the wipers must start rotating from 0,0,0 to 0,0,-45. Now, the situation is that Wipers are rotating but when I press "wipers toggle off" the wipers stop at exactly the same current rotation point where they are for example (0,0,-30). And when I press "wipers toggle on" again the wipers starts from weird different rotation point. Here is my code:

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Wipers : MonoBehaviour 
{
    [SerializeField] protected Vector3 m_from = new Vector3(0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F);
    [SerializeField] protected Vector3 m_to = new Vector3(0.0F, -45.0F, 0.0F);
    [SerializeField] protected float m_frequency = 1.0F;

    protected virtual void Update() 
    {
        if (ControlFreak2.CF2Input.GetAxis ("wipers") != 0) 
        {
            Quaternion from = Quaternion.Euler(this.m_from);
            Quaternion to = Quaternion.Euler(this.m_to);

            float lerp = 0.5F * (1.0F + Mathf.Sin(Mathf.PI * Time.realtimeSinceStartup * this.m_frequency));
            this.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(from, to, lerp);     
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your issue when turning on is that you are directly using `Time.realtimeSinceStartup` which also continues running while the routine is turned off of course! So you never know at which point the wipers will be when turned on.

  → You rather want to use the time since the wipers where started instead.
- Your issue when turning off is of course that you immediately stop moving.

  → You rather want to always complete a full cycle after the wipers have been turned off.

Instead of doing this in `Update` I would suggest to use a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html). Coroutines are way easier to control and maintain than doing stuff in `Update` directly. In fact they are like small temporary Update like routines and execute right after the real `Update` has finished.

A Coroutine you can let continue and complete a full cycle until it is actually done.

In Update you would only check the user input and start a routine (if none is running already) and the routine can run and terminate a complete cycle independently:

```c#
[SerializeField] protected Vector3 m_from = new Vector3(0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F);
[SerializeField] protected Vector3 m_to = new Vector3(0.0F, -45.0F, 0.0F);
[SerializeField] protected float m_frequency = 1.0F;

// TODO only for debugging
[SerializeField] private bool ControlFreak2Dummy;

private bool wipersOn;
private Quaternion from;
private Quaternion to;

private void Awake()
{
    // Store these once -> more efficient then recalculate them everytime
    from = Quaternion.Euler(m_from);
    to = Quaternion.Euler(m_to);
}

protected virtual void Update()
{
    // TODO switch these back
    //if (ControlFreak2.CF2Input.GetAxis ("wipers") != 0)
    if (ControlFreak2Dummy)
    {
         if(!wipersOn)  
         {
            StartCoroutine(Wipers());
         }
    }
}

// To make things easier for us this in itself closed routine is exactly ONE FULL wipers cycle
// so we can determine exactly when a full cycle is done or not
private IEnumerator Wipers()
{
    // block concurrent routines
    wipersOn = true;

    var duration = 1f / m_frequency;
    var timePassed = 0f;

    while (timePassed <= duration)
    {
        // Note: Your sinus factor calculation was a bit strange
        // (or maybe this early I'm way too stupid for maths lol ^^)
        // It was always minimum 0.5 and maximum 1, you rather want to pingpong between 0 and 1
        //
        // This now moves forth and back exactly once between 0 and 1
        var factor = Mathf.Sin(Mathf.PI *  timePassed / duration);

        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(from, to, factor);

        // increase timePassed by the time passed since last frame
        timePassed += Time.deltaTime;

        // allows Unity to "pause" here, render this frame and
        // continue from here in the next frame
        yield return null;
    }

    // make sur it really terminates in 0
    transform.localRotation = from;

    // tell others that this routine is done
    wipersOn = false;
}
```

[image]

Comment: when press start, the wipers starts but stops when return to 23 degree and then nothing happens.

Comment: oh wait I just made it way simplier actually :D

Comment: Thanks your v.v.much defHugo. Your is working absolutely fine.

Comment: Glad to help :) If this answer solves your question please feel free to mark it as accepted.